# Python alternating input and output

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, sys

I'm trying to write a "game"where the user enters a move and the "cpu player" outputs its response, after which the user enters another move and so on. E.g.

> $ enter a move #cpu prompt
>
> 5   #user's input
>
> 7   #cpu output
>
> 10  #user's  input
>
> 16  #cpu output
>
> 20 #user's input
>
> You win! #cpu's output
>
> $

I know how sys.argv provides a list of arguments on the command line, but what would I use so that my program reads each input line and outputs a value to which the user inputs another argument?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That looks like normal terminal behavior. You print something, then input something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=raw_input#raw_input) function built into Python. That should do exactly what you like.

```
playermove=raw_input()
```